# SQL Server Stored Procedure that returns updated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored proc that returns all records that are updated.

My update query is this:

```
UPDATE BatchItems 
SET [Status] = 'Processing' 
WHERE [Status] = 'Queued'
```

I'm just not sure how to return those specific records.

Comment: Can you select the records before you run the update? In effect, it gives you the same records before they were updated. I.e. Select * from BatchItems where Status 'Queued' and then run your update. Same net results

Comment: I don't want to do that because  records could have been inserted between the select and the update.

Comment: Okay sorry didn't know there were possible concurrency issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`OUTPUT INSERTED.[cols]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to fetch rows the statement has modified.

```
UPDATE BatchItems 
   SET [Status] = 'Processing' 
   OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE [Status] = 'Queued'
```

Example;

```
select 'Queued       ' as status, 1 as id into #BatchItems
insert  #BatchItems values ('Queued', 2)
insert  #BatchItems values ('XXX', 3)

UPDATE #BatchItems 
  SET [Status] = 'Processing' 
  OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE [Status] = 'Queued'

>>status       id
>>Processing   2
>>Processing   1
```

Comment: @marc_s It works perfectly with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, see update

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above you can use the OUTPUT clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=SQL.90).aspx

```
update BatchItems
set Status = 'Processing'
output inserted.*
where Status = 'Queued'
```

Comment: The output clause is only supported in SQL 2k5 or above.