# sql how to select and update at the same time

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a column `processed` it is value is zero for failure and 1 for success. I want to add a third temporary case, its value is 2.

my previous query is:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tableName WHERE processed = @processed";
```

I would like to do update for the rows that this selects makes. I can do that from .net of course, but I want to know if there is one query that can select the rows and update the process column at the same time.

i am working with sql server 2008

That question states a very old solution, which is the output, and I couldn't discover it my self.

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610509/getting-the-id-of-a-row-i-updated-in-sql-server) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984631/sql-server-stored-procedure-that-returns-updated-records) [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700786/sql-update-a-row-and-returning-a-column-value-with-1-query) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367018/get-updated-row) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414104/how-to-use-output-clause-of-sql-server-for-update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
UPDATE dbo.tableName 
SET processed = 2 --or whatever you want..
OUTPUT inserted.*
WHERE processed = @processed
```

From MSDN (Link above):

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
>   by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
>   returned to the processing application

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're wanting to do some kind of atomic record-lock on the rows selected.  Not sure about T-SQL, but in Oracle you could do this with an UPDATE table SET PROCESSED = 2 WHERE conditions RETURNING primary_key BULK COLLECT INTO array.  Then do a select * for the rows whose keys were stored in the array.

I think the T-SQL syntax would be something like UPDATE table SET PROCESSED = 2 OUTPUT primary_key INTO temp_table WHERE conditions.

Comment: so you are suggesting to change my enterprise's database to use Oracle?

Comment: seriously read my complain on the meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305838/how-can-i-avoid-duplicates-that-really-arent typical situation

Comment: I'm just suggesting you could try that kind of approach, translating it into T-SQL, if something equivalent to "returning / bulk collect into" is available.